# Importrange in Google Sheets with Index Function to get the latest budget

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, importrange

I am trying to import the latest budget[**single cell**] from worksheet 1 in the budget tab for the latest month into a summary table on to Worksheet 2. i'm trying to take the max month and import the budget into my summary table.

[image: Worksheet 1 Table Importrange error]

I've tried to use importrange function from the budget tab in worksheet 1 with the index function to Worksheet2.  Dates are in descending order in column B and the corresponding budgets in column D on the **budget tab**, however error is shown. Any help is appreciated!

```
=index(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wh8nZZQ6hCGQ2CB-jfDWxf3Z40v9Tg7SrvT6xI3aZNI","Budget!B9:D25"),max("Budget!B9:B25"),3)
```

[image: Budget Tab - Budget value to import into the summary table]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1Wh8nZZQ6hCGQ2CB-jfDWxf3Z40v9Tg7SrvT6xI3aZNI", "Budget!B9:D25"),
 "select Col3 order by Col1 desc limit 1", 0)
```

---

[image]

Comment: just wondering why the index doesn't read the date as a number

Comment: my guess is that you would need the same importrange under MAX too

Comment: Thanks so much @player0, if going by your example of importrange the latest budget cell was blank, would there be a way to take the next cell with a budget?

Comment: I dont see a reason why not, tho its hard to advise you if I don't see the dataset. can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: sure  @player0 - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WQbxrlRl3CF6Pq7TgmVVBSdBV2iMUj1_uziM8jwFmmQ/edit#gid=0 . Assuming we needed to sum the media budget and sum the value pulling that into the summary table - would that be possible? Given sometimes there are only one row per month. Also if there were to be blanks on the latest date row in media budget is it feasible to pull the max date cell with values

Comment: clarifying meaning that could be 2 budgets lines for the same month sometimes but sometimes it may just be one

Comment: see if this works for you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krp6V.png

Comment: just a little bit of luck :)